# Unable to run rhandsontable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to build a scheduler, in which a user can input the name in the table for each time slot. However, I am having difficulties running the rhandsontable in shiny. I get the following error message:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3547
Warning: Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput: Unexpected rhandsontable 
output for hotUnexpected htmlwidget output for hot
Stack trace (innermost first):
40: .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput
39: $<-.shinyoutput
38: $<- [C:\Users\USER\Documents\RProject\scheduler/app.R#31]
37: server [C:\Users\USER\Documents\RProject\scheduler/app.R#31]
 1: runApp
Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput(name, value, label) : 
  Unexpected rhandsontable output for hotUnexpected htmlwidget output for hot
```

This is my .app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(        
  ),

  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- data.frame(time=c("09-12","12-15","15-18","18-21","21-24","24-03","03-06","06-09"),
               monday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               tuesday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               wednesday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               thursday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               friday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               saturday=c("","","","","","","",""),
               sunday=c("","","","","","","",""))

output$hot<- rhandsontable(df, rowHeaders = NULL)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: this `output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df, rowHeaders = NULL)})` should work

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks, it works now!